# React Native: Access Redux store from Native side (swift/objective C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

Part of our React Native App lets users use it in the background while they use other apps.

If the user then force quits the app while our app is in the background we want to do some cleanup and send some analytics. Since we can't get the `applicationWillTerminate` event in React Native we need to do this cleanup in the native side.

So we were wondering if there is a way to access the Redux store in this event. Or what is the suggested way to handle this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, since your JS runtime (and with that the Redux store) will be gone as soon as a user kills the application